# Solve a system with in 3 space with a constraint?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equations:

$$
y = \frac{7x}{25}-3.28\\
z= 75y - \frac{20075}{14}
$$

$y$ must be constrained to 96. Given a value for $x$, what must $z$ equal in order to solve the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate the second equation to give $z$:  $z=75 \cdot 96-\frac {20075}{14}\approx 5766.07$ indpendent of $x$.  You can also evaluate the first to give $x$ and get $x = \frac{99.28 \cdot 25}7 \approx 354.57$.  This is the only solution.